# Setup WhatsApp status in Bluestack on a Windows 10 notebook

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, bluestacks

I have installed BlueStack on my Windows 10 notebook. I wanted to set up the status of my WhatsApp account. However, I couldn't find any option to navigate through and add a video file.

I could set up the status of my WhatsApp account by taking a new photo using my camera, but I want to add an already downloaded video file to my status.

Comment: Have you tried using an alternative gallery app to do that?

Comment: Thanks a lot, gallery app isn't involved in setting up whatsapp status.  Also, I don't know how to add/use an alternative gallery app on Bluestack program on my Windows notebook. I am just using Whatsapp on Bluestack. if I want to add an image or other media to Whtasapp contact,  I can click on "adding files" icon. Then,  I can select media or photo from my BlueStack Whatsapp gallery or from my Windows computer. However,  there are no options of navigating to select exiting media or photo file as Whatsapp status while setting up BlueStack WhatsApp status. take a new photo or video via camera.

Comment: I have installed Fish bowl.  But there is no option how to set up a photo as my Whatsapp status via Fish bowl.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Open Camera for Android.
2. Then, click on view picture (denoted by the most recent picture in the gallery on the upper right-hand corner).
3. Complete action using view picture if it asks for it.
4. Then click on the share icon on the image. Share pictures via WhatsApp. 5. When WhatsApp opens automatically, click on My status then send.

This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Bear in mind that I am using WhatsApp installed via Bluestack on my Windows notebook. When I search for open camera and installed open camera (look! I only searched for open camera without for Android) and launched it,  there were no options like view picture.

Comment: Have you tried installing opencamera on bluestacks itself, not on windows?

Answer (score -1):

1. Open your picture or gallery in Bluestack (if you don't have one, go get one).
2. Then select the picture or videos you want to use and click share.
3. Click WhatsApp, and then click My status.